# 1/2" diameter 5/8" thick clear plastic tube

Tags: siphon

My tube was flat in some parts of it, is there a way to make it more round so the liquid smoothly flows thru?

I think that was the reason I was seeing air bubbles in the tube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing air bubbles in the tubing because you're letting air in it somewhere (connections are the most likely place).  If this is the typical vinyl tubing that I think it is, just get some more.  Seriously, my local big box home improvement store sells 20 feet of the stuff for less than $8.

You should replace if from time to time anyway.

Comment: Grabbed another thing of tubing and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Any time.  I'm glad it worked out for you.